# TP-LINK Archer C20i router installing OpenWRT went wrong

Tags: linux, openwrt, router

I recently bought TP-LINK Archer C20i router and attempted to install OpenWRT. Now when I connect my router to the laptop it is not getting connected. The lights on the router are blinking (turn on and off).

The following is the procedure what I followed

1. Found the [OpenWRT wiki for my respective router](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c20i)
2. From there I downloaded [Chaos Calmer 15.05.1 ramips-mt7620-ArcherC20i-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips/mt7620/openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-mt7620-ArcherC20i-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin)
3. Now I connected my router to laptop and in browser URL typed 192.168.0.1 to open TP-LINK router settings.
4. Entered admin username and password
5. Now went in System Tools-> Firmware Upgrade
6. Selected the downloaded file which is ending with sysupgrade.bin and pressed upgrade.
7. Now the default gateway IP got changed from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.3.1.
8. But the weirdest thing is when I tried to connect to it with new default IP address from the browser, it is not getting connected.
9. The router lights are blinking

When I googled for the error I got to know that with the above procedure I should have downloaded the file which ends with factory.bin.

But now everything got screwed up. I am not able to access it. When I contacted TP-LINK customer care they are telling to buy a new one. If you change the default software then the warranty will be void.

How can I solve this issue, and recover access to this device?

Comment: You've picked the wrong (`sysupgrade`) image instead of the right one (`factory`). The (`sysupgrade`) are intended to be installed upon already having the OpenWrt installed, and only updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do recovery via [tftp](/questions/tagged/tftp). The [Page you already linked yourself above](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c20i) contains a section "Recovery (via tftp)"

The steps from there are:

1. Hold the WPS button during startup.
2. After 10 seconds the router will start trying to download a file ArcherC20iV1_tp_recovery.bin via tftp from a server with the IP 192.168.0.66 for 10 more seconds.

So, you need to get either the stock firmware from somewhere, or try again with Chaos Calmer suitably renamed.

If your problems persist, connect a serial [console](/questions/tagged/console) as also described on the OpenWRT wiki

Comment: Here is a description of where to get the Stock firmware, and some more recent firmwares: https://pwassi.privatedns.org/lede/archerc20i/